# Why Śrī Rāma practiced monogamy?

Tags: rama, marriage

I wonder what propelled him to not practice polygamy despite it being custom even followed by his father. Did he give any reason of his monogamy?

Comment: Dasharatha was polygamous because he didn’t have any children (As per the Smritis). Shanta was given in adoption to Romapada. So Kaushalya was childless. Thereafter he got married to the other two and yet remained childless. Otherwise most Ikshvaku kings were monogamous only. We see full fledge polygamy in only in Mahabharata. Well Bhagwan Vishnu can marry only Mahalakshmi. Mahalakshmi didn’t take multiple forms as in the case of Krishna Avatar

Comment: @Archit if this is an answer, please answer instead of making it a comment.

Comment: @Archit You forgot the 350 other women :)

Comment: @Surya I feel they’re not the wives of Dasharatha. They’re the wives of other royal members like maybe Sumantra, Vasishtha

Comment: @Archit I doubt that, because when Rama leaves to the forest, Dasaratha summons for "his wives", and Rama bows down to his "Maatarah" - mothers. That's not the same as bowing down to the ministers' wives.

Comment: Rams Avatar showed by practicehow ahuman being should live their life. Whereas krishna avatar showed by preaching Lord  Krishna had 16800 odd wife's still he vows his brahmCharya when reviving parkshut